# Checkboxes in if statement inside a for loop work in reverse

Tags: java, android, checkbox, tablerow

I have a for loop that displays 2 textviews and a checkbox in each of my tablerow in a table layout. I have an if statement that shows a toast to test the isChecked function of a checkbox, but the if statement works inversely except for the last table row. Why is that, and how do I fix it?

```
for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {

            tableRow1 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            textViewMaster = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textViewMaster.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("StudentID")));
            textViewMaster.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textViewMaster.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redactionbar));
            textViewMaster.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
            textViewMaster.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tableRow1.addView(textViewMaster);

            textViewMaster2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textViewMaster2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("LastName")));
            textViewMaster2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textViewMaster2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redactionbar));
            textViewMaster2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
            textViewMaster2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tableRow1.addView(textViewMaster2);

            tableRow1.setClickable(true);
            tableRow1.setLongClickable(true);
            tableLayout1.setClickable(true);


            checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            checkBox.setChecked(true);

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)
                {
                    if (checkBox.isChecked())
                    {
                        searchView.setEnabled(false);
                        arrayList.add(container1);
                        arrayList2.add(container2);
                        arrayList3.add(container3);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Its checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        arrayList.remove(container1);
                        arrayList2.remove(container2);
                        arrayList3.remove(container3);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            });

            checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tableRow1.addView(checkBox);
            tableLayout1.addView(tableRow1);

            c.moveToNext() ;
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does 'c.moveToNext() ;' refer to?

Comment: It's a cursor that declares a database raw query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Current implementation `checkBox` hold last CheckBox object which is created during last iteration of `for loop` so use second parameter of `onCheckedChanged` method which is if `true` means CheckBox is checked otherwise unchecked:

```
 @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)
   {
     if (b){ // or use compoundButton.isChecked()
       // code if checkbox is checked    
     } else{
       // code if checkbox is not checked
      }
}
```

Comment: I forgot that the b was the parameter needed for the if statement. It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use suggestion in other answer, but this would also work and would be a technique to use when you do not have a parameter you can use:

Create a new local variable, not a field so is different for each loop and mark is as `final` in order to be able to use it from the anonymous class.

```
final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());

//rest is same
checkBox.setChecked(true);

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)
    {
        if (checkBox.isChecked())
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
});
```